# Can someone synonymize [recaptcha] and [google-recaptcha]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

When I propose to make [recaptcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recaptcha) and [google-recaptcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-recaptcha) synonyms, the tag synonym suggestion system is telling me that:

> Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag.

The [recaptcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recaptcha) tag has 1500+ questions and a description of:

> reCAPTCHA is a system originally developed at Carnegie Mellon
>   University that uses CAPTCHA to help digitize the text of books while
>   protecting websites from bots attempting to access restricted areas.
>   On September 16, 2009, Google acquired reCAPTCHA.

[google-recaptcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-recaptcha) has 219 questions and a description of:

> reCAPTCHA is a free service to protect your website from spam and
>   abuse. reCAPTCHA uses an advanced risk analysis engine and adaptive
>   CAPTCHAs to keep automated software from engaging in abusive
>   activities on your site. It does this while letting your valid users
>   pass through with ease.

It's pretty obvious that these are one and the same. Both also link to google.com/recaptcha.

Can those with enough score in these tags make the synonym suggestion?

---

On a related note, I think it's absurd that to merely *suggest* a synonym (which still goes through a vetting process) is restricted to users that have answered questions in the tag. I'm pretty sure I can *suggest* a valuable synonym without having earned rep in it.

Comment: [The synonym system has been broken for a long time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127459).

Comment: It is good to note that actually there are TWO captcha owned by google. The first being recaptcha and the second being their own service that they made

Comment: @Sammaye The other CAPTCHA you're thinking of is only used by Google on certain site login and registration forms they operate, so there are essentially no legitimate questions which can be asked about it.

Comment: @duskwuff It can be used by devs too. I use it for some of my sites

Comment: @duskwuff in fact this is where you can go to get it https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

Comment: @Sammaye …er, that's quite obviously the same thing as Recaptcha!

Comment: @duskwuff no, they are two different libraries and two different techs

Answer (score 3):

I have suggested [google-recaptcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-recaptcha) as a synonym of [recaptcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recaptcha). It now needs four upvotes to be accepted.

If you have at least 5 total upvotes for questions tagged [recaptcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recaptcha), you can vote for the synonym here:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/recaptcha/synonyms

Comment: no... backwards! People confuse Google's recaptcha with non-Google captchas. Case point http://stackoverflow.com/q/15564841/792066

Comment: @Braiam There's over 20 times as many questions tagged [tag:recaptcha] as [tag:google-recaptcha]. I'm sure some people use the tag incorrectly, but that's a problem to be solved by retagging.

Comment: I'm not sure how is that relevant, the main tag would be google-recaptcha, no recaptcha.

Comment: I gave it a vote, now we just need 3 more votes...